# What is meant by parent component and child component in the sense of react and react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am new to ***React*** & ***React Native***, and doing my best to learn it well. During the learning i came to the lesson ***props and state*** but here one thing makes me confused and that is ***parent component*** and ***child component***.

When we create a component in the ***React*** or ***React Native*** it is created like that:

```
export default class myApp extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            // Do something ...
        );
    }
}
```

And that's it. So, why people say parent component and child component and so on.
Is the ***React.Component*** is the parent component or is the ***myApp*** is child component. How parent and child components communicate via the ***props and state***. Can please someone explain in easy words along with few examples, i will be glad.

Thanks !!!

Comment: In a component based architecture, you will have a HOC which will call your custom component and that will internally call some generic component. So with respect to your custom component, HOC is a parent component which will supply props. Your component will maintain its state, and based on provided props and computed state, you will pass props to this generic component, which is a child component.

Comment: Well React applications are build with a set of react components, which can be encapsulated in each other. So a component B inside component A is the child component of the parent component A. Anyone correct me please if i'm wrong, not using React myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In React.js and React Native, you render UI with components. So let say you want to build a `House` component. But first, you build a set of different components that you are going to use as building blocks such as a `Door`, `Wall` and `Window` components. Then you are going to use these components in your `House`'s `render` function to render it. These building blocks components in this example are child components and the `House` component is their parent component.

On a side note, this concept originally comes from the DOM although there you talk about nodes (parent node, etc) rather than components.

Comment: So, the child and parent concept is only inside the Class, outside of the class ? Right ?

Comment: It's not related to any concept of a class. This concept is not tied to JS or a language syntax. It's more of React mindset and jargon. I'd recommend you to read: https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html

Comment: Ok, Its clear now, but last and least, let say we have two components **class abc extends React.Component{}** and **export default class xyz extends React.Component{}**, So, can we pass something from **abc** to **xyz**or from **xyz** to **abc** ?

Comment: Components pass values to each other through `props`. You don't extend components from another usually. It's very important to understand that React favors composition over inheritance.

Comment: Is there any way to give you 1000000~ points ? Because i was very upset just because of this concept, and you clear my concept.

Comment: Nice analogy. Just a pointer, *child/parent* comes w.r.t to a component. So, `wall` component will consume `brick` component which is a child component **for wall** component.

Comment: @DaddyBoy no need to stress out. Most of the concepts are complex to understand but are usually derived from real world. So if you go back to their english meaning and try to relate, that will clarify some assumptions

Comment: @DaddyBoy I'm glad I was able to help :)

Answer (score 1):

`React.Component` is a parent for `myApp` *component class*.

While 'parent' and 'child' alone refer to React component hierarchy. `myApp` *component* is a parent for `Foo` *component*, and `Foo` *component* is a child of `myApp` *component*:

```
export default class myApp extends React.Component{
    state = { foo: true };

    render(){
        return(
            <Foo foo={this.state.foo} />
        );
    }
}
```

Parent and child component can communicate through props in one direction. A parent can pass something (e.g. its own state) to a child through props.

Comment: Ohhk, i was thinking that let say **class abc extends React.Component{}** and  **export default class xyz extends React.Component{}**, and i was thinking that the **abc** is the parent component of the **xyz** and **xyz** is the child component of the **abc** component.

Comment: No, it's about components themselves and not their classes. Since React components usually use virtually no inheritance except React.Component/PureComponent, there's no ambiguity.

Comment: So, the child and parent concept is only inside the Class, outside of the class ? Right ? –

Comment: More specifically, inside a hierarchy of components in `render` function. `myApp` and `Foo` could be functional components that don't inherit from React.Component but still maintain same relationship.

Answer (score 1):

As commented,

> In a component based architecture, you will have a HOC which will call your custom component and that will internally call some generic component. So with respect to your custom component, HOC is a parent component which will supply props. Your component will maintain its state, and based on provided props and computed state, you will pass props to this generic component, which is a child component.

---

**TL;DR**

#### Example:

**Requirement:**

You are trying to create a form that will accept 2 numbers and display their total.

**What you need:**

- A form component that will create 2 input fields.
- A input component that will accept value and return it to the caller.
- A validator that will check if the value entered is a number or not.
- A label to display total.
- An event to process inputs.

**Implementation:**

You start in a ground-up fashion with input components. You cannot use `<input type='text'` as it will not have your custom validator. You cannot use `<input type='number'` as it adds spinner. So you create a custom component which uses `type="text"` and write your own validator

Now for this component, its value cannot be the value entered by user as it can be NaN. So you need a variable to store the processed value. You also need this value to be created once and not every time to persist its value. This place is called **state**.

Now that you have an input component, you need to stitch it together. So you create a form with your custom components and uses handlers/functions for communication. These functions passed to components are called as **props**.

So, to summarize, state is something you as a component will hold and prop is what you get from external environment (*say some component*).

Now, in this component tree, who do you call *parent/child* component? It is always referred based on a context. So in above example, w.r.t `CustomInput` component, since `FormComponent` is calling it, that is its parent. Similarly, any component it is calling will be its child component.

Answer (score 0):

The parent/child component is an intuition not only the react/react native but to all mark up in general.

I assume you are conversant with html tag.

```
<div class='parent'>
    <div class='child'></div
</div>
```

From the script above div.parent is a parent tag to div.child and vice versa.

Similarly in react

```
export default class myApp extends React.Component{ 
    state = { foo: true }; 
    render(){ 
        return( 
            <Foo foo={this.state.foo} /> 
        );
    }
}
```

Foo is a child to myApp and myApp is parent to Foo.

This intuition is same in any mark up language

Comment: OMG, this was the problem i was confused because i came from HTML world, This is the extremely outstanding example man, thanks many time, stay blessed.

Comment: Thanks alot for the upvote @Daddy Boy(Funny name i must confess). This is actually my first upvote in this community as i am relatively new here. I always try to explain things as simple as i understand them. Thanks once more. Cheers